# Problem linking gfortran, relocation truncated to fit

Tags: linker-errors, gfortran, lapack

I am trying to link mingw64 compiled lapack 3.9.0 libraries statically on Windows. I run into the following linker problem when I do that:

```
libgfortran.a(read.o):(.text$_gfortrani_convert_real+0xb7): relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_REL32 against undefined symbol `strtoflt128'
```

I found a solution/workaround ([Linking error generating static executables after the lastest gfortran update](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/7023) ), but I do not know how to apply it. The solution is to add the flag `-Wl,--default-image-base-low` to the compiler/linker command line, but if I do that to my command line, g++ does not understand that. Maybe I have to add it somewhere else (gfortran when building the lapack libs?), but then I wouldn't know how as I'm using CMake, and everything is pretty much generated automatically.

Comment: What was your full command when you tried to apply the wrkaround? Was there any error message?

Comment: c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: unrecognized option '--default-image-base-low'